# Реализация функции которая переворачивает строку

Tags: javascript, функции

Начинаю изучать язык JavaScript и в некоторых задачах вообще не понимаю в чем суть.

Вот задание:

> Реализуйте функцию `reverse`, которая переворачивает строку.
>    Например:   `reverse('hello, world!');`

А вот ответ:

```
const reverse = (str) => {
  let i = str.length - 1;
  let result = '';

  while (i >= 0) {
    result = result + str[i];
    i = i - 1;
  }

  return result;
};
```

Comment: Пожалуйста , обьясните все детально почему и как все делаем

Comment: А что вы собственно от сообщества хотите? Я лично понять не могу...

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: прочитай сначала учебник про функции работы со строками и циклы - станет яснее

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще проще

```js
const rev = (str) => {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('')
};

console.log(rev('привет'));
```

А далее подробнее

Что делает `split('')`?

Метод `.reverse()` Может разворачивать только массив. Значит строку надо преарвтить в массив. Что и делает `split('')`

```js
const rev = (str) => {
  return str.split('')
};

console.log(rev('привет'));
```

Далее этот массив надо перевернуть, что и делает `.reverse()`

```js
const rev = (str) => {
  return str.split('').reverse()
};

console.log(rev('привет'));
```

Ну а далее `.join('')`, который собирает все это в одно слово